# How to prevent an Apollo Client Query from caching in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, apollo-client

[We can disable caching globally in jQuery by doing:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4303862/2009886)

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

I'm trying to find a similar option in Apollo Client. I've tried Middleware and Cache-Control headers without luck.

Is it possible to disable cache in a similar way (i.e., by appending a timestamp to the query string) as the previous jQuery option does?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the fetchPolicy to "[no-cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#ignore)". like this:

```
const defaultOptions = {
      watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        errorPolicy: 'ignore',
      },
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        errorPolicy: 'all',
      },
    }

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultOptions: defaultOptions,

});
```

Code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879016/how-to-disable-cache-in-apollo-link-or-apollo-client).

Comment: I tried this and IE11 still caches the request (Edge, and any other browser, does not cache it as expected). I think we only have two options: 1. Use a query string timestamp 2. Use Cache-Control headers (see stackoverflow.com/q/4303829/2009886). I'm looking for an option to intercept my Apollo queries and inject a timestamp to the query string (or a similar option).