# Disable cache when running vue-apollo queries manually

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo

I use vue-apollo for working with GraphQL.

I installed it via `vue add apollo` and as a result a have vue-apollo.js which I use for configuration.

Current configuration:

```
// Call this in the Vue app file
export function createProvider (options = {}) {

  // Create vue apollo provider
  const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient,
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        // fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      },
    },
    errorHandler (error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('%cError', 'background: red; color: white; padding: 2px 4px; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;', error.message)
    },
  })

  return apolloProvider
}
```

Want I want to do is to disable cache for any query. Right now it's disabled when I do queries via `apollo:` component property. But when I run queries manually via $apollo instance, it doesn't work.

It does work if I put fetchPolicy for every query, for example:

```
  const response = await this.$apollo.query({
        query: documentSetListQuery,
        variables: {
          ...mapFilters(this.getActualFilters(this.filters), whitelistFilters),
          regime: false
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
      })
```

Is it possible to setup `no-cache` globally if I run the query manually via `this.$apollo.query`? Just to avoid `fetchPolity: 'no-cache'` repetition

Comment: Maybe this answer to a similar question (regarding apollo-react however) can be of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48549667